# Playing all files in a directory with iTunes for Windows

Tags: windows, itunes, cmd.exe

iTunes on Windows.

Running from the directory with music in cmd:

```
iTunes.exe "file.mp3"
```

works perfectly, while

```
iTunes.exe "*.*"
```

doesn't work properly (seems that just opens iTunes; maybe does smth else, but it is invisible).

How do I play all files in a directory?

BTW, I have mingw installed, maybe it will help.